# golang urfave/cli run another binary with all args and flags

Tags: go, kubectl

I want to invoke other `urfave/cli` based CLIs, *e.g.*, `kubectl` with `myapp kubectl` command. For that, I've a minimal project

```
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── pkg
    └── cmds
        └── kubectl.go

2 directories, 4 files
```

`pkg/cmds/kubectl.go`

```
package cmds

import (
    "k8s.io/component-base/cli"
    "k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd"
    "k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util"

    _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth"
)

func Kubectl() {
    command := cmd.NewDefaultKubectlCommand()
    if err := cli.RunNoErrOutput(command); err != nil {
        util.CheckErr(err)
    }
}
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/user/repo/pkg/cmds"
    "github.com/urfave/cli/v2"
)

func main() {
    app := &cli.App{
        Commands: []*cli.Command{
            {
                Name:    "kubectl",
                Aliases: []string{"k"},
                Usage:   `Should run kubectl with all args and flags`,
                Description: `go run . kubectl version

                error: unknown command "kubectl" for "kubectl"
                exit status 1`,
                Action: func(cCtx *cli.Context) error {
                    strings.Join(cCtx.Args().Slice(), " ")
                    fmt.Println(strings.Join(cCtx.Args().Slice(), " "))
                    cmds.Kubectl()
                    return nil
                },
            },
            {
                Name:        "get",
                Aliases:     []string{"v"},
                Usage:       "Executes `kubectl get` with all args and flags",
                Description: `Apparently kubectl runs with root coomand context`,
                Action: func(cCtx *cli.Context) error {
                    fmt.Println(strings.Join(cCtx.Args().Slice(), " "))
                    cmds.Kubectl()
                    return nil
                },
            },
        },
    }

    if err := app.Run(os.Args); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

With this, I can now run `go run . get ...` and get expected `kubectl get ...` response. What I want is to run `go run . kubectl get ...` but this errors

```
error: unknown command "kubectl" for "kubectl"
exit status 1
```

How to run `NewDefaultKubectlCommand()` with `kubectl` command context (ie remove remove `kubectl from args slice)?